# jquery selecting manipulated strings

Tags: jquery

I have the problem with selecting strings:

```
var idToChange = $(obj).attr('id').replace('#', '');

window.location = $("'li .' + idToChange + ' a'").attr('href');
```

This doesn't reload the page but when I do `alert('li .' + idToChange + ' a');` I get the correct value, and when I use firebug console to get `('li .' + idToChange + ' a').attr('href');` I also get correct string. I think I am messing something up with quotes during selecting. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the double quotes, you can already see with the syntax highlighter that everything inside of `$(...)` is red (meaning the it is treated as string):

```
$("'li .' + idToChange + ' a'")
```

vs

```
$('li .' + idToChange + ' a')
```

Comment: I like it when the syntax highlighting in their question shows the error.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work.  And I tried doing alert on it , and I get undefined.

Comment: @bibek: Maybe it does not select the correct element... but if `$('li .' + idToChange + ' a').attr('href');` works for you in the console, then it should also in the code.

Comment: That's what I thought but when I do `alert($(obj).attr('id').replace('#', ''));` I get correct value, and then when I use that value in firebug console it finds it and it works nicely.

Comment: @bobek: Then you have to create a http://jsfiddle.net/ example, there is nothing more to say otherwise.

Comment: I removed 'li' from 'li .' and now it works :) Thanks for your help!